# How can I get the publci Ip of the ec2 instance and pass it in jenkins to build an container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have a Public IP from Jenkins slave which I can get it straight from the ec2 instance or else I can get that IP using curl command. The issue is while creating another server based on Jenkins slave I need to pass the Jenkins public IP in the aws cli command while creating stack from jenkins pipeline. But I am facing issues in passing that Jenkins slave ip in order to create n deploy services in another server. The Jenkins slave IP and docker ip should NOT be hardcoded.

Comment: Can you give some more information on where you are trying to get the IP from or execute the build from?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information so that we can assist you. You mention an EC2 instance, but you do not explain whether it is an existing instance, or a new instance, nor what you are doing with it.